# How to eager loading with laravel on a different naming convention

Tags: laravel, eager-loading

I have two tables. 'weeks' and 'dates'
The weeks table holds an 'startDate' and an 'endDate' Both columns a foreignKeys to the dates columns. The dates table holds an primary key id and the date.

```
weeks

| IDweeks | startDate | endDate |
|    1    |     2     |    6    |
```

```
dates

| IDdates | date |
|    1    | 12-03-2018 |
|    2    | 13-03-2018 |
.....
```

When I query the weeks, I always get the keys for startDate and endDate. I would like to get the values from the dates tables instead.

I´ve already tried to eager load the values like this:

#### weeks Modal

```php
class weeks extends Model
{
//....
    public function startDate()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\date', 'startDate', 'date');
    }
    public function endDate()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\date', 'endDate', 'date');
    }
//....
```

#### dates Modal

```php
class date extends Model
{

    protected $primaryKey = 'IDdates';
```

#### calling the 'with()' method

```php
    public function showWeeks() {
        $weeks = weeks::with('startDate')->get();
        return view('weeks')->with('weeks', $weeks);
    }
```

#### using in the view

```php
 @foreach ($weeks as $week )
    {{ $week->startDate->date }} // produces an error like: Trying to get property 'date' of non-object
    {{ $week->startDate }} // works but returns only the keys instead of the value of dates table.


@endforeach
```

### How can I load the results of the dates table when calling the weeks?

EDIT: edited a typo in the title

Comment: Just to confirm, are the fields(startDate, endDate) in weeks table of datatype 'date' or 'number' ?

Comment: Your code for relationship in model seems to be incorrect, it still should be `return $this->belongsTo('App\date', 'startDate', 'IDdates');` same for `endDate()`

Comment: startDate and endDate in the weeks table is an unsignedInteger ```$table->unsignedInteger('startDate')->unique();  $table->unsignedInteger('endDate')->unique();```

Comment: Unfortunately this ```return $this->belongsTo('App\date', 'startDate', 'IDdates');``` still does not work